# Google App Script: Hide column when value is "0" or "null"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a google app script running and I am trying to hide columns that contain cells or "null" or "0". The code I have underneath is hiding everything before column "P". Not sure why that's happening. Any thoughts would be helpful!

```
function hideColumnsIfZeroOrNull() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const reportSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Post Campaign Report (Attribution)");
  const firstRowToCheck = 19;
  const lastRow = reportSheet.getLastRow();
  const lastColumn = reportSheet.getLastColumn();
  const range = reportSheet.getRange(firstRowToCheck, 2, lastRow - firstRowToCheck + 1, lastColumn - 1);
  const data = range.getValues();

  const columnsToHide = [];
  for (let col = lastColumn - 1; col > 1; col--) {
    let hideColumn = true;
    for (let row = 0; row < lastRow - firstRowToCheck + 1; row++) {
      const value = data[row][col - 2];
      if (value !== 0 && value !== "" && value !== null && value !== "null") {
        hideColumn = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (hideColumn) {
      columnsToHide.push(col);
    }
  }

  Logger.log("Columns to Hide: " + columnsToHide);

  if (columnsToHide.length > 0) {
    columnsToHide.forEach(columnIndex => {
      const cell = reportSheet.getRange(firstRowToCheck, columnIndex + 1);
      const mergedRanges = cell.getMergedRanges();
      if (mergedRanges.length > 0) {
        const firstColumnIndex = mergedRanges[0].getColumn();
        const lastColumnIndex = mergedRanges[0].getLastColumn();
        reportSheet.hideColumns(firstColumnIndex, lastColumnIndex - firstColumnIndex + 1);
      } else {
        reportSheet.hideColumns(columnIndex + 1);
      }
    });
  }
}
```